# Incompatible if statement when migrating from MySql to SQL Server

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have this query

```
select if(flow_peymankar_type.title = '' , 
    flows.title, flow_peymankar_type.title) as title,
    flows.minRow, 
    [flow_peymankar_type].id,
    [flows].[file],
    [flows].isMandetory 
from flow_peymankar_type 
inner join flows 
    on flows.id = flow_peymankar_type.flowsId 
where [peymankarTypeId]=11     
order by flow_peymankar_type.code desc
```

and it's working fine in mysql.

But now I have to migrate to sql server 2008,
but this query is a problem for me and I don't know how to change it for working in sql server. plz help

Comment: Just change `if` to `iif`, and it should work. Alternatively, use a `CASE` statement

Comment: iif didn't work ! could you be more sq specific?

Comment: Please see my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, `IIF` is only available in sql server 2012 and later. Use `CASE` instead:

```
SELECT      CASE
               WHEN flow_peymankar_type.title = '' THEN flows.title
               ELSE flow_peymankar_type.title
            END AS title 
....
```